# Python - euclidean distance different size vectors

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I have a numpy array size (9126,12) and two reference cluster points (2,12) that I'm trying to calculate the distance to for the array in order to label them. I understand in practice how this is meant to happen but just can't implement it due to sending different size arrays.

Know I can use numpy.linalg but it's part of a home work assignment so not allowed to do so.

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9126,12) (2,12)

```
def euclid_dist(v1, v2):
    return np.sqrt(((v1-v2)**2).sum(axis = 1))


def check_euclid_dist(data, reference_vectors):
    npdata = data.to_numpy()
    dst = euclid_dist(npdata, reference_vectors)
    # Get the indices of minimum element in numpy array
    result = np.where(dst == np.amin(dst))
    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, but I think so you are! :) A distance can be calculated for two points usually, which lie in a 12-dimensional space here, right? The role of the reference point is important here. Do you need to do two distance calculations here for all the points in the first array? You could do euclid_dist(x,y[0,:]) and then euclid_dist(x,y[1,:]).

Comment: Sorry yes should have been clearer, need to do two distance calculations for 12-dimensional space vs two reference points! And now when you say it it's so obvious! thank you! Spent so many hours and for some reason not seen that simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the distance of each vector to each of the reference points by inserting an extra dimension in both arrays and let Numpy broadcast them against each other:

```
distances = np.linalg.norm(npdata[:, None, ...] - reference_vectors[None, ...], axis=-1)
```

Then you can find the nearest cluster by using `np.argmin`:

```
cluster_id = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)
```